# Postgres + Docker: pg_dump does not work from outside

Tags: postgresql, docker, pg-dump

I want to setup a cron script that automatically creates dumps from a specific **Postgres** database running in a **Docker** container. I know how to execute commands in a container from outside and also am familiar with *pg_dump*.

Somehow, for my container  and database , I can't seem to make it work:

```
docker exec <container> pg_dump -U postgres <mydb> > /pg-snaps/<mydb>_$(date).sql
```

I get the following error:

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /pg-snaps/<mydb>_<date>.sql
```

The directory */pg-snaps* exists. I can execute the same command inside the container, and it works. I have no idea why it doesn't work with `docker exec`. I looked up the methodology on how to do this, and it suggests the same as I want to do. Adding " " around the command to be executed also results in a 'no such file or directory'.

Comment: You shouldn't need `docker exec` here; you should be able to run `pg_dump` directly on the host (provided you have PostgreSQL client tools installed, and the database container has a published port).  That might resolve ambiguity around host vs. container paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this example:

```
docker exec -it <container> sh -c 'pg_dump -U postgres <mydb> > /pg-snaps/<mydb>_$(date).sql'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This does exactly what I intended